# Software for online lecture (mass-conference with slides)

Tags: presentation, webcam

Is there software for Online Lecture (where there are many people/clients with webcam), one presenter/server with webcam, and the presenter shows both his face and slide/presentation on each of clients' computer). When the lecture is finished, there would be question and answer session, where the server choose one person/client to be shown on each clients' computer, and so on..

**EDIT**: I prefer that the server software could be installed on our own servers.. and the ability to be used internally (with or without internet connection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BigBlueButton](http://bigbluebutton.org/) has everything you are looking for:

1 - Supports many people/clients with webcam & presenter with webcam
2 - Can show both face & slide presentation (with audio but I think that is understood)
3 - server choose one person/client to be shown on each clients' computer. We additionally used this feature for taking attendance

Additional features
1 - Group chat which everyone can see
2 - IM Chat that is you can chat with a particular person nobody else will see it
3 - Raise a hand (figuratively) that is a student can use this feature to raise a doubt/question
4 - Record & playback of live sessions 
5 - Whiteboard
6 - Desktop sharing

Comment: this is exactly what I want.. I believe this software can be installed locally right? (so we could use it without internet)

Comment: Yes you can locally run it as well within an Intranet.

Answer (score 3):

## [NetViewer Meet](http://www.netviewer.com/en/support/downloads)

NetViewer Meet is an online conference and screen sharing tool. It consists of two downloads: a **Moderator** and a **Participant** app.

As a **moderator**, you can:

- Control which screen to be shared, yours or a participant's
- Control who receives remote control over the displayed screen
- Select whose video signal to be transferred. You could transfer your own video, and grant rights for others to transfer theirs
- Control who is allowed to transfer their speech into the meeting
- Control session recording

These features should allow you to hold a lecture and a question/answer session afterwards simply by activating the asker's screen and voice/video signals. You could also appoint a participant as a co-moderator (in case you have a TA)

The **participants** are able to:

- View the screen and video selected by the moderator
- Use their pointers to point at items on the screen
- Share their voice, video, or screen (only after the moderator grants them the right to do so)

These features would allow the students to watch the lecture, and then participate in the question/answer session by sharing their own screen afterwards

Note that there has been an option to upgrage to [GoToMeeting](http://www.netviewer.com/en/gotomeeting) ever since NetViewer was acquired by Citrix, but I have not used that upgrade, so I can't give a definite recommendation

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, is this software requires connection to Citrix's servers? or can I use my own servers..

Comment: @Kokizzu According to [this FAQ page](http://www.netviewer.com/en/support/faq), you have to be connected to the NetViewer servers. You can embed the WebStarter applet on your website, but it still has to connect to their servers